# Join two tables based on multiple column comparison

Tags: sql, database, oracle19c, oracle

I have a country dimension table **COUNTRY_DIM** like below:

| ID | SHORT_NAME | FULL_NAME | ALTERNATE_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | USA | United States of America | United States |
| UK | UK | United Kingdom | Great Britain |
| IN | India | Republic of India |  |
| ROK | South Korea | Republic of Korea |  |
| DE | Germany | Federal Republic of Germany | Deutschland |

I have another table **COUNTRY_FACT** where I have Country Name and some values like below:

| COUNTRY_NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| United States | 30 |
| India | 6 |
| United Kingdom | 10 |
| South Korea | 2 |
| Republic of Korea | 1 |
| Germany | 4 |
| USA | 2 |

I want to join both the tables on **SHORT_NAME** first, if not matched then **FULL_NAME** if not matched then **ALTERNATE_NAME** and derive the Country ID.

So the output will be like below :

| COUNTRY_ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| US | 32 |
| IN | 6 |
| UK | 10 |
| ROK | 3 |
| DE | 4 |

I am using the below query:

```
select dim.country_id,sum(fact.value) value
from contry_fact fact
inner join country_dim dim
on
case when upper(country_name) = upper(short_name) then 1
when upper(country_name) = upper(full_name) then 1
when upper(country_name) = upper(alternate_name) then 1
else 0 end = 1
group by dim.country_id
```

> Is this the correct method to get the desired output or we can achieve it another way ?

I am using **Oracle 19c**

Comment: Generally there's no reason to wrap up the conditions in a `case` expression when you can just do the equality tests directly and chain them with logical operators (`and`/`or`, etc.)

Comment: Great Britain is not the same as United Kingdom, but OK. Just saying.

Comment: We (in *everyday speech*) call it "England" anyway, @TheImpaler :)

Comment: @Littlefoot Don't say that to a Scottish person... :[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to join once when you have multiple candidate join columns or any kind of conditional logic in the join clause (like that `CASE` statement). It creates a performance headache and limits the join methods Oracle can use.

Instead, join *separately* for each candidate join column, then use `COALESCE` in the order you want matching the priority to select the desired dimension:

```
SELECT COALESCE(d1.country_id,d2.country_id,d3.country_id) country_id,
       SUM(f.value) value
  FROM country_fact f
       LEFT OUTER JOIN country_dim d1 ON UPPER(f.short_name) = UPPER(d1.country_name)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN country_dim d2 ON UPPER(f.full_name) = UPPER(d2.country_name)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN country_dim d3 ON UPPER(f.alternate_name) = UPPER(d3.country_name)
 GROUP BY COALESCE(d1.country_id,d2.country_id,d3.country_id)
```

However that you're doing an aggregation suggests this is using an actual fact table rather than obtaining a dimension key to load a fact table from staging. If that's the case, you really shouldn't have text country strings in your fact table at all. It should already be replaced by the surrogate `country_id` at ETL time so this kind of query complexity by users isn't needed.

Comment: Yes , the fact table must contain the ID columns. But the data for the fact table we are getting from a upstream source , so we can not modify the ETL

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but does the job.

```
SQL> select d.id, sum(f.value)
  2  from country_dim d join country_fac f on
  3    f.country_name in (d.short_name, d.full_name, d.alternate_name)
  4  group by d.id
  5  order by d.id;

ID  SUM(F.VALUE)
--- ------------
DE             4
IN             6
ROK            3
UK            10
US            32

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively (and worse, as it scans the same tables too many times),

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select d.id, f.value
  3       from country_dim d join country_fac f on f.country_name = d.short_name
  4     union all
  5     select d.id, f.value
  6       from country_dim d join country_fac f on f.country_name = d.full_name
  7     union all
  8     select d.id, f.value
  9       from country_dim d join country_fac f on f.country_name = d.alternate_name
 10  )
 11  select id, sum(value)
 12  from temp
 13  group by id
 14  order by id;

ID  SUM(VALUE)
--- ----------
DE           4
IN           6
ROK          3
UK          10
US          32

SQL>
```

Comment: To reduce table scans: unpivot country dimension, join to the fact and aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution could be to use the `row_number` window function as follows:

```
select country_id, sum(value) as value from
(SELECT d.id country_id,
       f.value,
       row_number() 
        over (partition by f.rowid 
              order by case when d.short_name = f.country_name then 1 
                            when d.full_name = f.country_name then 2 
                            else 3 end) as rn
  FROM country_dim d
  join country_fact f 
    ON d.short_name = f.country_name
       OR d.full_name = f.country_name
       OR d.alternate_name = f.country_name ) t
where t.rn = 1
group by country_id;
```